# After react update useReducer hook requires 3 arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am ran into a problem while updating react and @types/react version to `16.9.0` (if I upgrade more, this issue still exists). It says that: `Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.`

Code:

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<State<D>, Action<D>>(reducer, {
    loading: false,
    data: undefined,
    error: undefined
  });
```

I have tried to find what is 3rd argument, but I found that it is just optional. Maybe someone had same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be defined without `State<D>, Action<D>` type variables:

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: false,
    data: undefined,
    error: undefined
});
```

Comment: Thats correct answer, I was able to figure out it by myself. But thanks for response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use type variables.

React expects 3 arguments because you were only supposed to give the reducer function definition in the type definition.

```js
interface stateInterface {
  loading: boolean,
  data: undefined | string,
  error: undefined | string,
}
function reducer(state: stateInterface, action: string): stateInterface {
  return // your reducer defintion here
}
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<(state: stateInterface, action: string) => stateInterface>(reducer, {
    loading: false,
    data: undefined,
    error: undefined
});
```